# Filesystem error while manually updating kernel

Tags: package-management, kernel, updates, dpkg, filesystem

Trying to manually install a new kernel version (linux-image-4.4.0-121-generic_4.4.0-121.145_amd64.deb) using dpkg, but it seems to fail, reporting only: `Failed to probe /dev/sdc3 for filesystem type`. Everything looks good up until that line, which is followed by "done".

I think I am trying to install it in the wrong place or mount point. I have /dev/sda1 and /dev/sda2, but also some other mounts. How do I determine the correct place to install this package and point it to there instead of /dev/sdc3?

Update:

Here is the command and output:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i linux-image-4.4.0-121-generic_4.4.0-121.145_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 237839 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack linux-image-4.4.0-121-generic_4.4.0-121.145_amd64.deb ...
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-4.4.0-121-generic (4.4.0-121.145) over (4.4.0-121.145) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-121-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-121-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/x-grub-legacy-ec2 4.4.0-121-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-121-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-121-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-121-generic
Setting up linux-image-4.4.0-121-generic (4.4.0-121.145) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Not updating initrd symbolic links since we are being updated/reinstalled 
(4.4.0-121.145 was configured last, according to dpkg)
Not updating image symbolic links since we are being updated/reinstalled 
(4.4.0-121.145 was configured last, according to dpkg)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-121-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-121-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-121-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-121-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-121-generic
W: mdadm: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 4.4.0-121-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-121-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 4.4.0-121-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-121-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.4.0-121-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-121-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/x-grub-legacy-ec2 4.4.0-121-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-121-generic
Searching for GRUB installation directory ... found: /boot/grub
Searching for default file ... found: /boot/grub/default
Testing for an existing GRUB menu.lst file ... found: /boot/grub/menu.lst
Searching for splash image ... none found, skipping ...
Found kernel: /vmlinuz-4.4.0-121-generic
Found kernel: /vmlinuz-4.4.0-119-generic
Found kernel: /vmlinuz-4.4.0-116-generic
Found kernel: /vmlinuz-4.4.0-75-generic
Found kernel: /vmlinuz-4.4.0-72-generic
Found kernel: /vmlinuz-4.4.0-71-generic
Found kernel: /vmlinuz-4.4.0-121-generic
Found kernel: /vmlinuz-4.4.0-119-generic
Found kernel: /vmlinuz-4.4.0-116-generic
Found kernel: /vmlinuz-4.4.0-75-generic
Found kernel: /vmlinuz-4.4.0-72-generic
Found kernel: /vmlinuz-4.4.0-71-generic
Updating /boot/grub/menu.lst ... done

run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-121-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-121-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-121-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-121-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-119-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-119-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-116-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-116-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-75-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-75-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-72-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-72-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-71-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-71-generic
Failed to probe /dev/sdc3 for filesystem type
done
```

On the machine I am working on there is sdc1-9. I did not configure this machine.

Comment: Start by showing exactly what command you typed and the results as displayed on screen (do not post a screenshot, copy the text).

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Please see update.

Comment: What is `sdc3` in `/etc/fstab`?